# Convert cloud builder docker to kaniko

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, kaniko

I have this in my cloudbuild.yaml that uses bash as an entrypoint. How would I use Kaniko on this? Or can I even do it?

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: bash
  args:
  - -c
  - |
    br="${BRANCH_NAME//\//_}"
    docker build --cache-from us.gcr.io/dev/asset-builder:$br \
         -t us.gcr.io/dev/asset-builder \
         -t us.gcr.io/dev/asset-builder:$br \
         -t us.gcr.io/dev/asset-builder:$SHORT_SHA \
         -f docker/prod/asset-builder.dockerfile .
  env:
  - 'BUILD=$BUILD_ID'
  - 'PROJECT=$PROJECT_ID'
  - 'SHORT_SHA=$SHORT_SHA'
  - "BRANCH_NAME=$BRANCH_NAME"
  waitFor: ['get cached images']
  id: 'build assets'
```